# Поиск отличий двух массивов

Tags: javascript, массивы

Доброго времени суток. У меня есть два массива , например `var arr = [1,2,3];` и `var x = [1,2,3,4,5];` . И есть скрипт, который удаляет одинаковые элементы массива

```
for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
        for(var j=0;j<arr.length;j++){
            if(x[i]==arr[j]){
                x.splice(i,1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Но вот проблема в том ,что если перемешать элементы массива, например `var arr = [1, 3, 2];` и `var x = [5,3,1,2,4]`, то в результате могут быть элементы, которые повторяются.

Comment: Часто меняете вопрос. Не успеваю менять ответ. Ваша задача - удалить из массива x все элементы, которые есть в массиве arr?

Comment: @Chubatiy прошу прощения , мне нужно из массива `x` узнать индексы всех елементов, которые не повторяються с елементами `arr`

Comment: так какой все-таки результат ожидается?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно следующий код

```
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    var isExists = false;
    for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        if (x[i] == arr[j]) {
            isExists = true;
        }
    }
    if (!isExists) {
        //Ваш индекс i
    }
}
```

`isExists` флаг нахождения совпадения. Т.е. мы перебираем весь массив `x` и сравниваем с каждым элементом массива `arr`.

Если находим совпадение - вывешиваем флаг.

После проверки если флаг не выставлен(т.е. совпадение не найдено) - то текущее значение `i` и есть индекс не повторяющегося элемента массива `x`

Comment: прошу прощения, возможно я чтот не так сделал, но если взять массивы `var arr = [];` `var x = [ '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7' ];`, то выдает только `0,1,2,3`

Comment: Странно. Только что выполнил - получил в результате 0 1 2 3 4 5 6

Comment: прошу прощения, в большой суматохе забыл убрать одну строчку, все работает отлично, спасибо вам огромное!

Answer (score 2):

```
var a1 = [6,3,5,1,2];
var a2 = [1,2,4];
var result = [];

a2.forEach(function(item) {
    var index = a1.indexOf(item);
    if (index !== -1) {
        result.push(index);
    }
});
```

В данном случае нет никакой необходимости пользоваться вложенным циклом for. Это сильно затрудняет чтение и отладку кода.

Comment: ты написал свою реализацию [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Да и в underscore.js есть _.filter, которой можно было воспользоваться. Просто я к тому, что решение значительно проще, чем с двумя циклами for и дополнительным флажком isExists.

Comment: undescore - Это библиотека, а я имел ввиду нативную функцию. так-то тут и indexOf не стоит использовать лучше либо Set либо собрать объект из массива и проверять свойства

Comment: Set имеет плохую поддержку для IE (в некоторых версиях и вовсе не реализован).